# How to return none or 0 for empty cells csv files

Tags: python

I have looked over the site for ways to do this but to no success.

So I'm looping through two csv files together and when I get to an empty string/ cell it gives me error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I understand what it means but this is what I have tried.

```
def normalise(students_file, units_list):
    file1 = open(students_file, 'r')
    data1 = file1.readline().splitlines()

    file2 = open(units_list, 'r')
    data2 = file2.read().splitlines()


    for line in data1:
        line = line.split(",")
        for row in data2:
            row = row.split(",")
            for n in range(1, len(row), 2):
                for i in range(1, len(line), 1):
                    if i == '':
                        pass
                    else:
                        print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
```

I know this code works because the output for the first increment is 0.6 which is what I wanted, but then the second increment is trying to divide an empty string and since int() cannot convert an empty string it runs an error.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `line[i]` or `row[n]` is an empty string?  It'd be great if you could post a simple [mcve] with expected output.  That will help to clarify your question and also allow others to confirm their solutions match what you're looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't check `i == ""` (this can't happen) but maybe `line[i] == ""` or `row[n] == ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the comment said.

In your code, I think there might be multiple potential problems will occur.

So I think you might want to check the `line[i]` and `row[n]`
I am not sure what you want to react if it is an empty string.

But I could fix this and leave the react space to you.

```
def normalise(students_file, units_list):
    file1 = open(students_file, 'r')
    data1 = file1.readline().splitlines()

    file2 = open(units_list, 'r')
    data2 = file2.read().splitlines()

    for line in data1:
        line = line.split(",")
        for row in data2:
            row = row.split(",")
            for n in range(1, len(row), 2):
                for i in range(1, len(line), 1):
                    #if i == '':
                    # i would not be '' because it comes from range()
                        #pass
                    #else:
                        #print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
                    if line[i] == "" or row[n] == "":
                        pass
                        # you could do somethings likes assigning some of them as 0.
                    else:
                        print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
```

Maybe it might not be a empty string and also some word.
you could use `try ...except...`

```
def normalise(students_file, units_list):
    file1 = open(students_file, 'r')
    data1 = file1.readline().splitlines()

    file2 = open(units_list, 'r')
    data2 = file2.read().splitlines()


    for line in data1:
        line = line.split(",")
        for row in data2:
            row = row.split(",")
            for n in range(1, len(row), 2):
                for i in range(1, len(line), 1):
                    try:
                        print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
                    except:
                        print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            for i in range(1, len(line), 1):
                if i == '':
```

That `if` can never be `True` since `i` will be an integer. You probably meant `if line[i] == '':` ?

Another approach is to use `try` blocks:

```
try:
     print(int(line[i]) / int(row[n]))
except:
    # do whatever you need to do when cell is empty 
    # or whatever other error occurs, for example division by 0...
```